# How to upload images by saving to local storage with unique names?

Tags: javascript, image, upload

I'm a complete beginner and just started teaching myself code a couple days ago, so if this is not the right way to do it, feel free to let me know how you would do it instead.

I am trying to upload multiple images onto a webpage using javascript. So far, I have been able to save the data URL to local storage, but every time I select a new file, the saved URL get overwritten. Then, when I click "Choose File," all of the images become the same. Is there a way to save the data URL with unique names without having to change it in javascript every time?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>||Working with elements||</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">The text above has been created dynamically.</div>

  <div>
      <label for="name"></label>
      <input type="file" id="name">
    </div>

</body>

<script src="test.js">
    </script>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
            if(this.files && this.files[0]) {
                const x = document.querySelector('img'); 
                 x.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        });
    });


document.querySelector("#name").addEventListener("change", function() {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem("recent-image", reader.result);
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

document.body.onclick = addElement;

function addElement () { 
  // create a new div element 
  const newDiv = document.createElement('img'); 
  const nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
  

document.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const recentImageDataURL = sessionStorage.getItem("recent-image");
    if (recentImageDataURL) {
        newDiv.setAttribute("src", recentImageDataURL);
    }
});


  const currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 
}
```

Comment: Line `sessionStorage.setItem("recent-image", reader.result);` overwrittes content every time. You need to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

The key of your [session-store](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)-entry is always the same: `recent-image`.

You need to use a **different, unique key for each image**.
Then you need a way to choose which of these keys you want to show.

(Alternatively you could store a list or collection with all the images, instead of only one image per key.)

There are many different ways to create a unique key, because there are many different ways to **define what *unique* means**. There is lots of information about creating unique keys, but the topic is more complex than one might think. Be prepared to read a lot, or just choose a simple way that is good enough for now. E.g.

- use a counter
- use the current date-time in milliseconds
- use a random number
- a combination of the above

A simple solution would be like this:

```
    let recentImageId = '';

    // ...

    //-- a very simple 'unique key' function
    const getUniqueImageId = function(){
        return 'image_' + Date.now();
    }

    // ...

    recentImageId = getUniqueImageId();
    sessionStorage.setItem(recentImageId, reader.result);

    // ...

    const recentImageDataURL = sessionStorage.getItem(recentImageId);
```